# OWL Protégé how to proper use object restriction creator

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

According to Protégé tutorial, class restrictions are created using the object restriction creator on the on the "Superclasses" section of the "Class Description" view. However, some scientific papers creates class restrictions on the  "Superclasses" section of the "Object Property Description" view. What is the diference? If there is no difference, which is correct according to OWL? Figure one shows an example of each scenario.

[image]
[image]

Adding the Superclasses section of the Object Property Description image for better understanding

[image]

Comment: What is the "Superclasses section of the Object Property Description view"? The only things you can define for properties are domain, range, inverse properties, super properties and some characteristics like functionality. And defining something for the property means it's some kind of "global" restriction. On the other hand, adding a restriction on the superclass of a class is indeed just "locally" to the class resp. its instances.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help. I do understand the concepts of class restriction but I don't understand why some Ontology designers uses it on the section of the Object Property Description view (I added I figure so I could see what I mean). If there is the "global restriction", who it works?

Comment: So you don't understand domain and range of a property. Let's assume there is a domain `C` for the property `p`. Then the following holds: For each individual `s` in the ontology that is related by property `p` to some other individual (or literal) `o`, i.e. there is a property assertion axiom `p(s, o)`, we can infer that `s` belongs to `C`.

Comment: The domain of an object property I think I got it right. But the range of a object property I did't fully understand yet. For example, using the Pizza tutorial from Protégé. The object property "hasTopping" has the domain "Pizza" and range "PizzaTopping". If I change its range to "hasTopping some PizzaTopping" what changes?

Comment: The range of the object is similar, just for the objects of the property assertion: Let's assume there is a range `C` for the property `p`. Then the following holds: For each individual `o` in the ontology that is used in a property assertion with property `p` as the target from some source individual `s`, i.e. there is a property assertion axiom `p(s, o)`, we can infer that `o` belongs to `C`.

Comment: Regarding your question, that would totally change the semantics: first you can infer that whatever is used as object with the property `hasTopping` belongs to class `PizzaTopping` - which perfectly makes sense, right? With your modification, it would mean that the object would itself have some `PizzaTopping` as topping. E.g. `SalamiPizza SubClassOf hasTopping some Salami`. 1. `Salami is a PizzaTopping` 2. `Salami hasTopping some PizzaTopping`

Answer (score 1):

In the picture you posted there is no superclass section for object properties - those represented are subproperty axioms.

As discussed in the comments, global and local restrictions on properties can be expressed through domain/range axioms on the property or with restriction superclasses in other classes, however the two approaches satisfy very different requirements - the classic example being `hasDescendant`, which can be globally restricted to have domain and range as `Living Organism`, and which can be locally restricted as in:

`Person and all hasDescendant Person`

restricting all persons to only have persons as descendants.

Comment: Thanks for the support but I still can't visualize how the two approaches satisfy different requirements. I know I they do. However I can't see the diference. Do you mind extend your example a little bit?